# linux c++: libaio callback function never called?

Tags: c++, linux, events, callback, aio

I'm on ubuntu 16.10 with g++ 6.2, testing libaio feature:

```
1. I was trying to test io_set_callback() function
2. I was using main thread and a child thread to talk by a pipe
3. child thread writes periodically (by alarm timer, signal), and main thread reads
```

I hope to use "callback" function to receive notifications. It didn't work as expected: callback function "read_done" is never called

My questions:

```
1. I expected my program should call "read_done" function, but actually not.
2. Why the output prints 2 "Enter while" each time? 
I hope it only print together with "thread write msg:..."
3. I tried to comment out "io_getevents" line, same result.
```

I'm not sure if callback mode still need io_getevents? So how to fix my program so it work as I expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to integrate `io_queue_run(3)` and `io_queue_init(3)` into your program.  Though these aren't new functions, they don't seem to be in the manpages for a bunch of currently shipping distros.  Here's a couple of the manpages:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/io_queue_run.3.html
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/io_queue_init.3.html

And, of course, the manpages don't actually say it, but `io_queue_run` is what calls the callbacks that you set in `io_set_callback`.

**UPDATED:** Ugh.  Here's the source for `io_queue_run` from libaio-0.3.109 on Centos/RHEL *(LGPL license, Copyright 2002 Red Hat, Inc.)*

```
int io_queue_run(io_context_t ctx)
{
    static struct timespec timeout = { 0, 0 };
    struct io_event event;
    int ret;

    /* FIXME: batch requests? */
    while (1 == (ret = io_getevents(ctx, 0, 1, &event, &timeout))) {
        io_callback_t cb = (io_callback_t)event.data;
        struct iocb *iocb = event.obj;

        cb(ctx, iocb, event.res, event.res2);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

You'd never want to actually call this without the `io_queue_wait` call.  And, the `io_queue_wait` call is commented out in the header included with both Centos/RHEL 6 and 7.  I don't think you should call this function.

Instead, I think you should incorporate this source into your own code, then modify it to do what you want.  You could pretty trivially add a timeout argument to this `io_queue_run` and just replace your call to io_getevents with it, instead of bothering with `io_queue_wait`.  There's even a patch here that makes io_queue_run MUCH better: https://lwn.net/Articles/39285/).

Comment: Well, it seems that it really doesn't!  See my update... in short, maybe just take the code I posted and add a timeout to it?

Comment: Hind, let me know if my answer helped you out!